# Whats happening Here and also What's the output? (No clue)

Tags: c++, function, pointers, output

The code is below. Please explain and also give the output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace::std;

int main() {
//  clrscr();
    int sum(int(*)(int), int);
    int square(int);

    int cube(int);
    cout << sum(square, 4) << endl;
    cout << sum(cube, 4) << endl;
    getch();

//  return 0;
}

int sum(int(*ptr)(int k), int n){
    int s = 0;
    for(int i =1; i <= n; i++){
        s +=(*ptr)(i);
    }
    return s;
}

int square(int k){
    int sq;
    sq =k *k;
    return k*k;
}


int cube(int k){
    return k*k*k;
}
```

No clue what's happening ! Please help me understanding this code. Specially in function

```
int sum(int(*)(int), int);
```

Not able to understand the above syntax in particular. But it would be help full to explain the whole code.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: There is a tool out there called a debugger.  With it you can step through the code line by line and watch it run.  Also `type (*possible_name)(parameters)` is a function pointer.

Comment: The strange looking code is a declaration that the parameter to the function is itself another function with one parameter of type int. Think of it like this, you are passing the address of the function into another function. The called function can then use that address to call the function which it points to.

Comment: @Slava  I know about pointers and functions.But this syntax is new to me

Comment: @DewangGupta So, did you try doing, at least, **some** research about it, before asking here?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yeah but not much .Tomorrow is my exam and this one is troubling me and I am running out of time as in India it's 11:30 PM and I also haev to sleep

Comment: Good luck with the exam...

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: @DewangGupta And now, you'll learn, that you shouldn't leave everything for your last night. In addition to that, exams will never contain stuff, that isn't covered, so that's your fault for not listening.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius that' s a good lesson

Comment: I wish that my answer should help you to prepare for your exam. Good luck for your exam.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what your program actually does:

When `n = 4`, the function `sum(square, 4)` is invoked.

- This in turn calls the `square()` method and computes the value of
  `*ptr` as `1` and then `s` will become `1` adding `0+1`. `*ptr` was
  assigned the value as `1` by calling the `square()` method which
  returns the value `1*1` which in turn gets assigned to `*ptr`.
- When i = 2, again the `square()` method is invoked and the value of
  `4` gets assigned to `(*ptr)(2)` since it's `2*2` that's returned by
  the method `square()` in this case. The value `4` gets added up to the value in `s` which was `1` and the value of `s` becomes `1+4=5`.
- When i = 3, again the `square()` method is invoked and the value of
  `9` gets assigned to `(*ptr)(3)` since it's `3*3` that's returned by
  the method `square()` in this case. The value `9` gets added up to the value in `s` which was `5` and the value of `s` becomes `5+9=14`.
- Finally, when i = 4, again the `square()` method is invoked and the value of
  `16` gets assigned to `(*ptr)(4)` since it's `4*4` that's returned by
  the method `square()` in this case. The value `9` gets added up to the value in `s` which was `14` and the value of `s` becomes `14+16=30`.
- The value `30` is returned by the function and this is obtained by
  the `main()` where this method was invoked.

The working of the call `sum(cube, 4)` is quite similar to the above explanation. The only difference is that its the `cube(int)` method is being invoked and the value that gets assigned to `(*ptr)(i)` will be `i*i*i` which gets returned from the `cube()` method. The value of `s` will initially be zero which gets added up to `s = 1 (0+1)`, `s = 9 (1+8)`, `s = 36 (9+27)` and finally `s=100 (36+64)` which is returned to `main()` method where it was invoked.

In other words, your program will work similar to the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(std::string, int);
int square(int);
int cube(int);

int main() {

    std::cout << sum("square", 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sum("cube", 4) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int sum(std::string value, int n) {
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (value == "square") {
            s = s + square(i);
        } else if (value == "cube") {
            s = s + cube(i);
        }
    }
    return s;
}

int square(int k) {
    return k*k;
}

int cube(int k) {
    return k * k * k;
}
```

I suggest that you use a `std::cout` in the `for` loop inside the `sum()` method of your program to see and analyze the results yourself. You can also use a debugger to see the workflow of your program if your IDE supports that.